# Variable declaration and assignment inside a constructor in C++

Tags: c++, class, vector, constructor

For the following code:

```
    class mgraph
    {
        private:
            int n;
            vector <vector <int>> vec;

        public:
            mgraph(int);
            void connect(int, int, int);
            void disconnect(int, int);
            void isconnected(int, int);
            void AddNode();
            void show();
    };

    mgraph::mgraph(int nodes)
    {
        n = ++nodes;
        vector <vector<int>> vec(n, vector<int>(n, 0));
        this -> vec = vec;
    }
```

Why doesn't the vec assigned to vec (using this pointer) get destroyed as soon as the constructor's task is over. I got the desired values (not the garbage values) after doing this but shouldn't the vector vec created in the constructor get destroyed after the constructor's task is over?

Comment: Why do you think _should_ it (`this->vec` if I understand correctly) be destroyed?

Comment: @churill I guess because constructor is like any other function. The variables created in it (in stack) would be destroyed once the scope of the function ends. I guess if we say that the vector allocates memory in heap, maybe then it won't be destroyed after constructor's task is done but I am not sure about that.

Comment: You could also use `mgraph::mgraph(int nodes): vec(n, vector<int>(n)) { ... }` which would avoid making a copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, `vec` is an automatic variable, so its scope is confined to the constructor. Its lifetime ends thus on exiting the constructor and it's destroyed.

However, the line

```
this -> vec = vec;
```

is a *copy assignment*. The content of `vec` is *copied* into `this->vec`, the implementation of `std::vector` takes care of that. So it doesn't matter anymore what happens to the local `vec`, `this->vec` has its own copy from now on.

You mention pointers... no pointers are involved. Just some copying.